# How can I correct this switch case in php?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Please let me know how can I complete this switch code:

```
switch ($urlcomecatid) {
case "50":
case "51":
case "52":
case "109":
case "110":

do nothing and exit from switch


otherwise:

header ("Location:http://www.mysite.com/tech/tech.php");
break;
}
```

Comment: PHP has documentation on the switch statement -> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: What about reading the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch ($urlcomecatid) {
    case "50":
    case "51":
    case "52":
    case "109":
    case "110":
        //do nothing
        break;
    default:
        header ("Location:http://www.mysite.com/tech/tech.php"); exit();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers ,i tested all ,the function exit() is needed.

Comment: I've had this problem before, the exit() after header() is always required!

Answer (score 2):

The `break` keyword will end processing in the switch statement.

The `default` block will be executed if none of the cases are matched.

```
switch ($urlcomecatid) {
    case "50":
    case "51":
    case "52":
    case "109":
    case "110":
        //do nothing and exit from switch
        break;
    default:
        header ("Location:http://www.mysite.com/tech/tech.php");
        exit(); // this line shouldn't be needed but it's good practice
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> do nothing and exit from switch

`break;`

The `break` keyword inside the `switch` block means exit this block and continue execution after the `switch` block.

And use `default:` instead of `otherwise:`

The default case matches everything else that was not matched by the other specified cases.

```
switch ($urlcomecatid) {
    case "50":
    case "51":
    case "52":
    case "109":
    case "110":
        break;
    default:
        header ("Location:http://www.mysite.com/tech/tech.php");
        break;
}
```